# Migrating ROM, RWO persistent volume claims from in-tree plugin to csi in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I currently have a ROM, RWO persistent volume claim that I regularly use as a read only volume in a deployment that sporadically gets repopulated by some job using it as a read write volume while the deployment is scaled down to 0. However, since in-tree plugins will be deprecated in future versions of kubernetes, I'm planning to migrate this process to volumes using csi drivers.

In order to clarify my current use of this kind of volumes, I'll put a sample yaml configuration file using the basic idea:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
  - ReadOnlyMany
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test
        image: busybox
        # Populate the volume
        command:
        - touch
        - /foo/bar
        volumeMounts:
        - name: test
          mountPath: /foo/
          subPath: foo
      volumes:
      - name: test
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: test
      restartPolicy: Never
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: test
  name: test
spec:
  replicas: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test
        image: busybox
        command:
        - sh
        - '-c'
        - |
          # Check the volume has been populated
          ls /foo/
          # Prevent the pod from exiting for a while
          sleep 3600
        volumeMounts:
        - name: test
          mountPath: /foo/
          subPath: foo
      volumes:
      - name: test
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: test
          readOnly: true
```

so the job populates the the volume and later the deployment is scaled up. However, replacing the `storageClassName` field `standard` in the persistent volume claim by `singlewriter-standard` does not even allow the job to run.

Is this some kind of bug? Is there some workaround to this using volumes using the csi driver?

If this is a bug, I'd plan to migrate to using sci drivers later; however, if this is not a bug, how should I migrate my current workflow since in-tree plugins will eventually be deprecated?

**Edit:**

The version of the kubernetes server is `1.17.9-gke.1504`. As for the storage classes, they are the `standard` and `singlewriter-standard` default storage classes:

```yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  labels:
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: EnsureExists
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
  name: standard
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
---
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  annotations:
    components.gke.io/component-name: pdcsi-addon
    components.gke.io/component-version: 0.5.1
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
  labels:
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: EnsureExists
  name: singlewriter-standard
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
provisioner: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

While the error is not shown in the job but in the pod itself (this is just for the `singlewriter-standard` storage class):

`Warning FailedAttachVolume attachdetach-controller AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume "..." : CSI does not support ReadOnlyMany and ReadWriteOnce on the same PersistentVolume`

Comment: AFAIK you can't change the `storageClassName` of a `PVC`. This field is immutable. You will need to create `PVC` with desired `storageClass` and copy the data (if you need it).

Comment: @DawidKruk, I know, what I meant is deleting the test sample and recreating it with a different `storageClassName`, or just changing all the names `test` by `test-new` if you want them to be side by side. This is just a sample yaml configuration that would work with the `default` storage class but not the `singlewriter-standard` storage class.

Comment: To fully understand the setup you're having please provide the `YAML` definitions of your `storageClasses`. Also please tell which `GKE` version are you using? As for the `Job` that fails, please include the output of `$ kubectl describe job JOB-NAME`.

Comment: @DawidKruk, I've just edited the question to include the extra information. I've just realized my previous comment said `default` storage class instead of `standard` storage class as in the question; this was my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message you encountered:

```sh
Warning FailedAttachVolume attachdetach-controller AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume "..." : CSI does not support ReadOnlyMany and ReadWriteOnce on the same PersistentVolume
```

is not a bug. The `attachdetach-controller` is showing this error as it doesn't know in which `accessMode` it should mount the volume:

> For [ReadOnlyMany, ReadWriteOnce] PV, the external attacher simply does not know if the attachment is going to be consumed as read-only(-many) or as read-write(-once)
>
> -- *[Github.com: Kubernetes CSI: External attacher: Issues: 153](https://github.com/kubernetes-csi/external-attacher/issues/153#issuecomment-500347886)*

I encourage you to check the link above for a full explanation.

---

> I currently have a ROM, RWO persistent volume claim that I regularly use as a read only volume in a deployment that sporadically gets repopulated by some job using it as a read write volume

You can combine the steps from below guides:

- Turn on the `CSI` Persistent disk driver in GKE

  - *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: How to: Persistent volumes: Gce-pd-csi-driver](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/gce-pd-csi-driver)*
- Create a `PVC` with `pd.csi.storage.gke.io` provisioner (you will need to modify `YAML` definitions with `storageClassName: singlewriter-standard`):

  - *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: How to: Persistent volumes: Readonlymany disks](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/readonlymany-disks)*

Citing the documentation on steps to take (from `ReadOnlyMany` guide) that should fulfill the setup you've shown:

> Before using a persistent disk in read-only mode, you must format it.
>
> To format your persistent disk:
>
> - Create a persistent disk [manually](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/preexisting-pd) or by using [dynamic provisioning](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes#dynamic_provisioning).
> - Format the disk and populate it with data. To format the disk, you can:
>
>   - Reference the disk as a `ReadWriteOnce` volume in a Pod. Doing this results in GKE automatically formatting the disk, and enables the Pod to pre-populate the disk with data. When the Pod starts, make sure the Pod writes data to the disk.
>   - Manually mount the disk to a VM and format it. Write any data to the disk that you want. For details, see [Persistent disk formatting](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#formatting).
> - Unmount and detach the disk:
>
>   - If you referenced the disk in a Pod, delete the Pod, wait for it to terminate, and wait for the disk to automatically detach from the node.
>   - If you mounted the disk to a VM, detach the disk using `gcloud compute instances detach-disk`.
> - Create Pods that access the volume as `ReadOnlyMany` as shown in the following section.
>
> -- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: How to: Persistent volumes: Readonlymany disks](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/readonlymany-disks)*

---

Additional resources:

- *[Github.com: Kubernetes: Design proposals: Storage: CSI](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/storage/container-storage-interface.md)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Blog: Container storage interface](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/01/15/container-storage-interface-ga/)*
- *[Kubernetes-csi.github.io: Docs: Drivers](https://kubernetes-csi.github.io/docs/drivers.html)*

---

#### EDIT

Following the official documentation:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: How to: Persistent volumes: Readonlymany disks](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/readonlymany-disks)*

Please treat it as an example.

Dynamically create a `PVC` that will be used with `ReadWriteOnce` accessMode:

`pvc.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc-rwo
spec:
  storageClassName: singlewriter-standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 81Gi
```

Run a `Pod` with a `PVC` mounted to it:

`pod.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox-pvc
spec:
  containers:
  - image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
    name: busybox
    command:
      - "sleep"
      - "36000"
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /test-mnt
      name: my-volume
  volumes:
  - name: my-volume
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: pvc-rwo
```

Run following commands:

- `$ kubectl exec -it busybox-pvc -- /bin/sh`
- `$ echo "Hello there!" > /test-mnt/hello.txt`

Delete the `Pod` and wait for the drive to be unmounted. Please do not delete `PVC` as deleting it:

> When you delete a claim, the corresponding PersistentVolume object and the provisioned Compute Engine persistent disk are also deleted.
>
> -- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Persistent Volumes: Dynamic provisioning](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes#dynamic_provisioning)*

---

Get the name (it's in `VOLUME` column) of the earlier created disk by running:

- `$ kubectl get pvc`

```sh
NAME      STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS            AGE
pvc-rwo   Bound    pvc-11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555   81Gi       RWO            singlewriter-standard   52m
```

Create a `PV` and `PVC` with following definition:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-rox
spec:
  storageClassName: singlewriter-standard
  capacity:
    storage: 81Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  claimRef:
    namespace: default
    name: pvc-rox # <-- important
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: <INSERT HERE THE DISK NAME FROM EARLIER COMMAND> 
    # pdName: pvc-11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555 <- example
    fsType: ext4
    readOnly: true
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc-rox # <-- important
spec:
  storageClassName: singlewriter-standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 81Gi
```

You can test if your disk is in `ROX` accessMode when the spawned `Pods` were scheduled on multiple nodes and all of them have the `PVC` mounted:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 15
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /test-mnt
          name: volume-ro
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: volume-ro
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: pvc-rox
          readOnly: true
```

- `$ kubectl get deployment nginx`

```sh
NAME    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
nginx   15/15   15           15          3m1s
```

- `$ kubectl exec -it nginx-6c77b8bf66-njhpm  -- cat /test-mnt/hello.txt`

```sh
Hello there!
```

Comment: Thank you; however, I get that warning when if I try to attach that volume to a pod as a ReadWriteOnce volume. Is there something I'm missunderstanding? Is there something extra I should add to the yaml of my job to make sure it tries to consume the volume as ReadWriteOnce instead of confusing the `attachdetach-controller`?

Comment: You need to create a `PVC` with only `ReadWriteOnce` accessMode. After that, when you are done and your disk is unmounted from a pod, you can create a `PV` and a `PVC` from this earlier created drive with a `ReadOnlyMany` accessMode.

Comment: How do I create the `pv` and `pvc` from the drive I created before? Is it possible to create two PVC with the same underlying drive? I have only created `pvc`s dinamically so far, so I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: @RaúlArturoChávezSarmiento I will update my answer with an example how I've managed to do it.

Comment: @RaúlArturoChávezSarmiento I updated my answer with an example. Please take a look.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. At the beggining I thought it was a bug because I thought the controller should assume `RWO` if `readOnly` was `false` (I still think it should do so, but it is what it is). I tried resizing, but it seems `singlewriter-standard` does not allow that; I do not usually resize, so I'm fine with that, though.

Comment: Here we are 2 years later but the issue hasn't been addressed; moreover, the GCP guide to ReadOnlyMany has vanished. The `temporary workaround` still holds true; i was able to get it to work on GKE 1.22.8 with some extra remarks:
1. The `StorageClass.provisioner` should be `pd.csi.storage.gke.io`; 
2. The `PersistentVolumeClaim.claimRef.namespace` must be set to a value